# Inner <div> is slightly overflowing parent <div> width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set up a basic webpage but my header and footer  are slightly overflowing the parent div on the right hand side. I have tried multiple combinations of clear: both and floats however cant seem to get it.

```css
    body {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    clear:both;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .wrapper {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    margin-top: 210px;
    margin-bottom: 210px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1500px;
    height: 100%;
    }

    .header {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: inherit;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .headerContent {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1500px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: ;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
      <div class="header">
        <div class="headerContent">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing `box-sizing: border-box;`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  margin-top: 210px;
  margin-bottom: 210px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1500px;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: inherit;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.headerContent {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1500px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: ;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="headerContent">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: `box-sizing: border-box;` property to all classes where you use border.